# Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module - Python Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy a Python lambda via instructions from a Dockerfile, but I keep getting the ImportModuleError. I will show the Dockerfile and project structure below.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY src/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD [ "src.lambda-processor.problem_processor_lambda.problem_handler.lambda_handler" ]
```

**Project Structure**

```
parent-folder/
-src/
---lambda-processor/
------problem_processor_lambda/
---------processor_handler.py
```

**Note:** The handler function name within processor_handler.py is `lambda_handler`.

**Error**

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'src.lambda-processor.problem_processor_lambda.problem_handler.lambda_handler': No module named 'src'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

There are two other StackOverflow answers that are a bit similar, but I'll explain what confuses me.

[Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module (lambda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295947/runtime-importmoduleerror-unable-to-import-module-lambda)

This question above refers to a missing library that might need to be installed with PIP, but the issue here is that this is instead a directory leading to the lambda handler; not a library to install.

[Lambda Python Docker - [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76600062/lambda-python-docker-error-runtime-importmoduleerror-unable-to-import-modul)

This one above is more like the problem I'm facing, but I can't seem to implement the solution correctly. I think there is something about COPY that I'm not getting correct.

Answer (score 0):

You folder is called `lambda-processor`, not `problem-processor`.

Comment: Sorry about that. When I posted the question, I changed some of the names of the folders, but I didn't update the names in the CMD part; they should be updated now.